# Flag record that is successful upserted in a Batch execution

Tags: apex, batch

Have a Batch class that get values from a custom Object and create or update records in another Object. I'm having problem to mark the record from the first object as completed/processed when the corresponding target record is upserted. Summing up, The records from object A have to update or create records in Object B, and only after that the records from A are marked as processed. How I can accomplish that?

Right now I'm using Try catch, but even when a record is not created on object B the flag from A is marked as true. For example, if I try to create an Account (object B) but in my Object A the name is missing, batch will be processed as success, account is not created but the flag on A will be True.

Comment: As usual, seeing the code you have here would likely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use try-catch; use a partial-update pattern instead.

**NOTE**: This code is not technically bulkified (`createOrUpdate` needs to be bulkified if any queries are involved); it is meant to be illustrative.

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Object1[] scope) {
  Object2[] recordsToUpsert = new Object2[0];
  for(Object1 recordToProcess: scope) {
    recordsToUpsert.add(createOrUpdate(recordToProcess));
  }
  Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(recordsToUpsert, false);
  for(Integer i = 0, s = results.size(); i < s; i++) {
    if(results[i].isSuccess()) {
      scope[i].Status__c = 'Success';
    } else {
      scope[i].Status__c = 'Failed';
      scope[i].Error__c = results[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage();
    }
  }
  update scope;
}
```

Comment: Sfdcfox as always being great. Got it, thanks.